# Creating a basic adapter for searchview that uses asynctask

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, searchview

So I'm making this student project Android app that I use to search movies online.

The problem I'm having is that even though there is tons of material to read, I don't quite comprehend how adapters for searchview results are supposed to be made. I know what kind of data the query returns, but I still don't know how to make an adapter for it.

I'm only at a beginner level in Java and Android programming, but this project really fired me up and I've been working on it day and night. If you have any tips (to improve my code) please do share them.

```
public class SearchActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.searchactivity);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

        new doMySearch().execute(query);
    }
}

private class doMySearch extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String parameters = (params[0]);
        JTomato jtomato = new JTomato("gibberish-cencored");
        jtomato.setPage_limit(1);
        List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();

        String total = String.valueOf(jtomato.searchMovie(parameters, movies, 0));
        return total;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }
    }
}
}
```

The data this search should return (if the search word were hulk) is as follows: [The Incredible Hulk, Hulk, HULK VS., Hulkamania Forever, Hulk Hogan's All-Time Champ, Hulk Hogan - The Missing Matches] and as many more to be found with that search word. I'm using a Java client for rotten tomatoes API that does most of the coding for me (http requests and json object parsing).

Comment: Please be more specific. What part of using an adapter are you having trouble with? If you followed any sort of tutorial, then what part of the tutorial did you not understand? Right now the only answer to your question is to read [the ListAdapter docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) and to use the [setListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#setListAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29) method, which is like saying do your own research.

Comment: I dont understand where the adapter is supposed to be made. Should i do it in th asynctask onpostexecute or is it made earlier like in the oncreate. I might be burning out from the stress and thats why i dont get it.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to display your results in a `ListView`? Because simply creating an adapter seems pointless.

Comment: I want to display the results as a list in the searchview. Also i'd want it so that when i choose one of the results, it does another asynctask fetch. Afaik ill just do onclick listener for the list and call the execution from there. I just need to know to display the results from the first search in a list. If i understood anything right from the searchview tutorials is that if i do it correctly, it displays the results under the "searchbar".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use the class [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

You can convert the string you receive into an array of strings, and then create an `ArrayAdapter` with the list of strings. If you set that adapter as the activity's list adapter, it will show the names of the movies in the activity.